# Having problems with adding a second line to my timeseries graph

Tags: r

I have a dataset that consists of 3 columns (`dates`, `unemployment rate`, and `seasonally adjusted unemployment rate`), I am trying to graph this in a time series graph. However, I can only get it to work for either `unemployment rate` or `seasonally adjusted unemployment rate`, and an unable to get both on the same plot at the same time.

I have attempted to use different methods such as ggplot and plot from answers found on SO, however I am having no success.

This is my code so far, where plot data represents the dataframe where my data is stored.

```
pd <- plotdata
Pd <- ts(pd[,2], frequency = 12, start = 2000)
plot(as.xts(Pd), type="l", col="red", major.format = "%b-%y", ylab="Unemployment Rate",
     main= "Unemployment Rate over Time")
lines(ts(pd[,3]), type = "l", col = "blue")
```

Expected result would be a graph with 2 lines on. However, 'lines' does not seem to add an additional line, and if I try and produce the time series with pd instead of pd[,2] or pd[,3] it creates a mess that looks nothing like what I am looking for. Thanks

[image: My graph for unemployment]

Comment: please add the result of `dput(head(pd))`

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(77L, 58L, 134L, 1L, 153L, 115L
), .Label = c("Apr-00",............, class = "factor"), 
    Actual = c(2.9, 3, 3, 2.8, 2.6, 2.7), Adjusted = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

>

Comment: You need to convert your `Date` values to actual dates (they're factors). Look around, in SO there are plenty of examples on how to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs some more detail. What are the name of your columns?

Using ggplot, here is how you would plot the series:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

pd$Date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(pd$Date))

ggplot(data = pd, mapping = aes(x = Date)) +
   geom_line(aes(y = Actual)) +
   geom_line(aes(y = Adjusted))
```

Comment: my columns titles are "Date", "Actual" and "Adjusted", I have tried using the ggplot however I think it may not be working due to the format of my dates, which are in Jan 2000 for example. My [,2] can be replaced by [Actual], and [,3] by [Adjusted]

Comment: OK I have updated my answer to correct your date issue, please mark if correct.

Comment: It comes up with following error:
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Comment: @JoelAlcedo try `as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(Date)))` so you can jump over they being factors

Comment: @oliverg99 are you using your Pd data or your pd data when it throws that error? What output do you see when you run str(pd)?

Comment: it says Date is factor and the other two are nums

Comment: Ok well try my re-updated code based on suggestion from @PacoDive

Comment: pd$Date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(pd$Date))

If you do this, and then re-run str(pd), does the output say your first column is a date?

Comment: This changes the format to Date, however all my dates become NA

Comment: And the original date column is read in as "Jan 2000", "Feb 2000", etc, correct?

You may want to try reading your data in once again without any modification, then run the code I sent you. I would expect it to work unless there is some relevant information associated with the data missing. Give it a shot

Comment: Yes correct, how do you mean without modifications, the dates have come from using excel

Comment: I have figured it out, it worked once I opened my file using .xlsx instead of .csv, thanks for all the help